# Decision tree problem

Tags: machine-learning, self-study, random-forest, boosting

I stumble upon this question.
We are solving a classification problem using a Decision Tree. When increasing the depth of the tree the accuracy improves until it stagnates at 90%. Why is this an unexpected behavior? Can you offer a plausible explanation?

I think we re are suffering from underfitting. Am I correct in my thought?
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Per the question, we keep on increasing the depth of the tree. So can this be underfitting?

Comment: Also, please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: @StephanKolassa. Therefore you think it is a straight overfitting?

Comment: No, it's not overfitting, either. Consider an extremely simple example. There is only a single predictor with a constant value of 42, and we have 10 observations, 9 of class A and one of class B. What will your trees look like? What accuracy will you get?

Comment: Also, [what does this tell you about accuracy as an evaluation metric](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/312780/1352)?

Comment: @StephanKolassa. So this is not unexpected behavior. As per your view model does not suffer neither underfitting nor overfitting?

Comment: Exactly. I would definitely not consider this unexpected. Can you formulate what causes accuracy to stagnate?

Comment: @StephanKolassa. I cannot formulate  what causes accuracy to stagnate. Can you help with plausible explanation.

Comment: Accuracy can stagnate because there are multiple observations with *identical* predictor values but *different* class memberships. A decision tree (and any other "hard" classifier) will assign the same fitted class to all such instances (because it could only assign different classes if the predictors differ, and they don't). It would be better to output a *probabilistic* classification and evaluate this using proper scoring rules, see the link in my earlier comment.

Comment: @StephanKolassa. Many thanks. Therefore all hard classifier more or less are going to suffer with such kind of issue. We need a proper scoring rules in order to evaluate them.

Comment: [That is exactly my position.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/312780/1352) Note that this is not unanimously accepted, especially not so among the ML community ([see, e.g., here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/601106/1352)), so if this is in the context of a formal course, be prepared that your instructor might see things differently.